# Can't access special vehicle list in gta 5

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v, xbox-one

When I'm in the garage of any 3 players on gta 5 for my Xbox One it says to access the Xbox store for new downloadable content but can't find anything in the Xbox store. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Xbox one installs all DLC automatically as game patches so the only thing in the store are the **Shark Cards** for in game currency, unlike on 360 where expansions packs had to be installed individually to unlock the access to the in game cars.